# Selenium Missing text value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python & beautifulsoup to extract the data, but for some reason it is doesn't see the text value.

HTML page has:

```
<div ng-if="!order.hidePrices" style="white-space: nowrap;" class="ng-binding ng-scope">$ 1,599.00</div>
```

Python code:

```
for price in prices:
    price_value = price.find('div', {"class":"ng-binding", "class":"ng-scope"})
    print(price_value)
```

And python output is missing text value:

```
<div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="!order.hidePrices" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>
```

The HTML file has no other class with that name. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a running driver instance, the do this :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ng-binding.ng-scope"").text)
```

class name with spaces have no support in Selenium, so try to use css selector.

**update :**

```
for div in soup.select('div.ng-binding.ng-scope'):
    print(div.text)
```

also you can do :

```
print(soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'ng-binding'}, {'class': 'ng-scope'}))
```

**Update 1:**

See [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) what official docs says.

### html.parser Advantages

```
Batteries included

Decent speed

Lenient (As of Python 2.7.3 and 3.2.)
```

### html.parser Disadvantages

```
Not as fast as lxml, less lenient than html5lib.
```

Read [here for more detailed docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

> An HTMLParser instance is fed HTML data and calls handler methods when
> start tags, end tags, text, comments, and other markup elements are
> encountered. The user should subclass HTMLParser and override its
> methods to implement the desired behavior.

Comment: great! This works, but how can we do this if I am using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I think you can do `print(price_value.text) ` should help you past this issue.

Comment: '''print(price_value.text)''' it returning blank

Comment: The method to get element text with BS is `.get_text()` see my answer...

Comment: also you can use `find_all` like above to match it, try it out and let me know.

Comment: using  .get_text()  gives me below error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: cause there is not `get_text`, it is `.text`. Did you try `for div in soup.select('div.ng-binding.ng-scope'):
    print(div.text)` from above ?

Comment: for div in soup.select('div.ng-binding.ng-scope'):     print(div.text)
This return blank.

Even if you see the original output, there is no $$ value.

Comment: No, because it is `NoneType`.  you get nothing into the `price_value` object because you are using wrong command or locator

Comment: @user1222006 :  see if this css `div.ng-binding.ng-scope` is unique, then you should get the proper output. Can you check in dev tools that we have unique entry ?

Comment: yes, it is unique for the prices. The page has multiple items and that class is unique for the price. 
For some reason, I am not able to extract the price, but I can successfully extract other item detail from the page.

Comment: Can you share the page URL ?

Comment: unfortunately, no. We have restricted access to that page and cannot share it. Sorry!

Comment: @cruisepandey I was using html parser to parse the page
`soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')` but after removing it it worked.
`soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)`
Do we know what does html.parser do?

Comment: An HTMLParser instance is fed HTML data and calls handler methods when start tags, end tags, text, comments, and other markup elements are encountered. The user should subclass HTMLParser and override its methods to implement the desired behavior.

Comment: also can you try with `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")` ?  and see if that works, also I have updated my answer above, do check it out and let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. Your locator seems to be not unique.
2. `price_value` here is a web element. To retrieve it's text you shoul apply `.text` on it
3. You are using BS, not Selenium here.

See if this will work

```py
for price in prices:
    price_value = price.find('div', {"class":"ng-binding", "class":"ng-scope"})
    print(price_value.get_text())
```